# Errors using Parallel::ForkManager

Tags: perl, parallel-processing

I'm trying to run a Perl script that uses [Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel%3a%3aForkManager):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Parallel::ForkManager;
use LWP::Simple;

my $pm= Parallel::ForkManager->new(10);

for my $link (@ARGV) {
    $pm->start and next;
    my ($fn)= $link =~ /^.*\/(.*?)$/;

    if (!$fn) {
        warn "Cannot determine filename from $fn\n";
    }
    else {
        $0.=" ".$fn;
        print "Getting $fn from $link\n";
        my $rc=getstore($link,$fn);
        print "$link downloaded. response code: $rc\n";
    };

    $pm->finish;
};
```

But I get the following errors:

```
File::Path version 2.06 required--this is only version 1.08 at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/File/Temp.pm line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/File/Temp.pm line 14.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Parallel/ForkManager.pm line 441.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Parallel/ForkManager.pm line 441.
Compilation failed in require at parallel.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at parallel.pl line 3.
```

How can I resolve them?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue: always `use warnings; use strict;`. You don't need `;` after the closing bracket of `for` and `if/else` blocks: `for (@foo) { # do something }`

Comment: how did you install Parallel::ForkManager?  it seems you did it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your version of File::Path.

As the error says, you're running version 1.08, but the version of ForkManager that you're running is dependent upon version 2.06.

Note also, that it appears that it is actually File::Temp, which has the File::Path dependency, while P::FM has a dependency on File::Temp.

Either way, you need a more recent version of File::Path.

Answer (score 0):

Perl 5.8.8 is from 2006. Upgrade to a supported version

Comment: Minor nitpick: `Parallel::ForkManager` supports Perl 5.8 (it [passes all its tests with Perl 5.8.8](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/P/Parallel-ForkManager.html?grade=1&perlmat=2&patches=2&oncpan=1&distmat=1&perlver=5.8.8&osname=ALL&version=1.06) on CPAN testers). The OP's version of `File::Path` is the issue here (although of course you're right, nobody should be running Perl 5.8 anyway).